# obtener un dato del ultimo insert realizado

Tags: jquery, base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

El caso es el siguiente, tengo dos tablas relacionadas en postgres, entiendase

Urbanizacion y Casas

en Urbanizacion tenemos los sig datos

```
idurb(PK-NoIncremental,varchar)| nombreurb | calle | idcasas(el campo
idcasas es una FK )
```

y en la otra Casas tenemos los sig datos

```
idcasas(PK-NoIncremental-varchar) | numeroCasa | propietario
```

El problema es este, con INSERT mando a llenar de primero la tabla Casas la cual es completamente llenada por el usuario, su numero de casa y el nombr del propietario y el Id de su casa, sin embargo, necesito relacionarla con la primera tabla por lo que necesito el idcasas q recien acabo de crear para a parte de llenar la tabla con los datos idurb, nombreurb y calle(q normalmente llenara el usuario desde el formulario), tambien necesito ingresar el id casas q recien fue creado, para poder relacionarla entre ambas, pense que realizando inserts normales, la FK que se autocompletaria por si sola, pero no fue asi, hay algun query q me permita obtener un dato q recien se ingreso para insertarla en otra tabla?

estos querys los hago desde nodeJS y los datos los obtengo desde un formulario en angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Obtener el id de una pk autonumérica recién insertada

Supongo que puedes hacer el insert de algún modo en tu back-end (php, node.js, java, no importa el concepto es el mismo).

Lo que puedes hacer para obtener el id es usar la cláusular `RETURNING` de la sentencia `INSERT` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-insert.html.

Algo así como

```
INSERT INTO (numeroCasa, propietario) VALUES (77, 'María') RETURNING idcasa;
```

Por ejemplo en `node.js` con `pg` quedaría así:

```
var mi_numeroCasa=77;
var mi_propietario='María';
const result = await client.query(`
    INSERT INTO (numeroCasa, propietario) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING idcasa
`, [mi_numeroCasa, mi_propietario]);
var idcasa = result.rows[0].idcasa;
```